# Bootstrap and DataTables - Jquery Error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Im not very clued up on frontend coding, so please bear with me.

Initially, my website used MVCContrib grid and utilised, it's own css style. I have until recently, converted my site to use Bootstrap. Now, because of this, MVCContrib doesn't work - well, I do not know how to incorporate it(MVCCOntrib) into Bootstrap as I have tried.

Nevertheless, Im now using straight HTML and razor to now output my table grid. I'm trying to use my existing dataTable js files for pagination, sorting, etc .. However, im constantly getting an error:

" Unable to get property 'pageButton' of undefined or null reference"

I do not know  what im doing wrong. This is how my page looks .. the trimmed version .. I just changed the names, else all is the same

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

@model grepTMVC.Models.THeaderModelList

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "T Requirer";
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "T Requirer";
}


<head>
<meta content="IE=11.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Bid Or Travel</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/dataTables.bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<meta name="GENERATOR" content="MSHTML 11.00.9600.17037" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#example').DataTable();

});
</script>

</head>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                        <table id="example" class="table table-responsive" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>T ID</th>
                                <th>D/s</th>
                                <th>created date</th>
                                <th>Close</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tID)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dde)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.creationDate)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.close)
                                    </td
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
}

</html>
```

Please can someone assist ..

The above error is targeted on dataTables.bootstrap.js

Below is the function where the error is pointing to in the js file:

```
/* Bootstrap paging button renderer */
DataTable.ext.renderer.pageButton.bootstrap = function ( settings, host, idx, buttons, page, pages ) {
  var api     = new DataTable.Api( settings );
  var classes = settings.oClasses;
  var lang    = settings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
  var aria = settings.oLanguage.oAria.paginate || {};
  var btnDisplay, btnClass, counter=0;

  var attach = function( container, buttons ) {
    var i, ien, node, button;
    var clickHandler = function ( e ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ( !$(e.currentTarget).hasClass('disabled') && api.page() != e.data.action ) {
        api.page( e.data.action ).draw( 'page' );
      }
    };

    for ( i=0, ien=buttons.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
      button = buttons[i];

      if ( $.isArray( button ) ) {
        attach( container, button );
      }
      else {
        btnDisplay = '';
        btnClass = '';

        switch ( button ) {
          case 'ellipsis':
            btnDisplay = '&#x2026;';
            btnClass = 'disabled';
            break;

          case 'first':
            btnDisplay = lang.sFirst;
            btnClass = button + (page > 0 ?
              '' : ' disabled');
            break;

          case 'previous':
            btnDisplay = lang.sPrevious;
            btnClass = button + (page > 0 ?
              '' : ' disabled');
            break;

          case 'next':
            btnDisplay = lang.sNext;
            btnClass = button + (page < pages-1 ?
              '' : ' disabled');
            break;

          case 'last':
            btnDisplay = lang.sLast;
            btnClass = button + (page < pages-1 ?
              '' : ' disabled');
            break;

          default:
            btnDisplay = button + 1;
            btnClass = page === button ?
              'active' : '';
            break;
        }

        if ( btnDisplay ) {
          node = $('<li>', {
              'class': classes.sPageButton+' '+btnClass,
              'id': idx === 0 && typeof button === 'string' ?
                settings.sTableId +'_'+ button :
                null
            } )
            .append( $('<a>', {
                'href': '#',
                'aria-controls': settings.sTableId,
                'aria-label': aria[ button ],
                'data-dt-idx': counter,
                'tabindex': settings.iTabIndex
              } )
              .html( btnDisplay )
            )
            .appendTo( container );

          settings.oApi._fnBindAction(
            node, {action: button}, clickHandler
          );

          counter++;
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't include both `~/Scripts/bootstrap.js` and `~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js`. Any one of them would do. Secondly can you show the code where the `pageButton` is used to identify the error ?

Comment: Another thing that springs to mind is that you have 5 header cells (`th`) but each row only has 4 cells (`td`). A cool thing to do is first check if the table works without DataTables, if it does then it should be fine with DataTables... though not always.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will send through the error message tonight when I can logon to my site .. Ps. Apologies, it was 5 .. I cut and pasted incorrectly, I will correct ..

Comment: @Nikhil, - I have edited my initial post to now include your request.. Thanks Naren

Comment: @annoyingmouse - I have edited accordingly, Thanks

Comment: What happens if you don't include the `dataTables.bootstrap.css` or `dataTables.bootstrap.min.css` files?

Comment: I still get the same error as the error is coming from the js file, dataTables.bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the issue. I was using jquery.dataTables.js version 1.9.4 whereas I should be using version 1.10.11

Answer (score 0):

If it says

> Unable to get property 'pageButton' of undefined or null reference

it clearly means it is not able to find the table defined in your HTML. Inside your `<tbody>`. I can see the 4th `<td>`tag is not closed properly. It is `</td`**(with a missing `>`)**. Probably this is why.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dde)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.creationDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.close)
            </td
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and had updated all of the related js files. I found the problem to be that IE was caching the older version of jquery.dataTables.js. Clearing the cache fixed this.